# What should the layername be in gdal_rasterize for loop?

Tags: bash, shapefile, raster, gdal

I'm new to Linux and am currently trying to run this code in BASH on a set of shapefiles:

```
for file in /mnt/hgfs/Shared/*.shp ; do
gdal_rasterize -l ??? -burn 1 -tr 0.5 0.5 -te -180 -90 180 90 $file rast2
gdal_merge.py -o rast1 rast2 rast1
done
```

rast1 is an empty raster used to bind the following rasters to. I can't figure out what the syntax after -l should be in this code...I think the rest runs fine. I've tried using $file but the terminal gives me the following error:

```
Unable to find layer /mnt/hgfs/Shared/SHAPE1.shp, skipping.
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: I've never used GDAL, and am in no way familiar with it.

Since the bottom of http://www.gdal.org/gdal_rasterize.html indicates that a layer name of "mask" can be used with "mask.shp", I suggest stripping the extension from `$file` and using that as the layer name:

```
gdal_rasterize -l $(basename $file .shp) -burn 1 -tr 0.5 0.5 -t -180 -90 180 90 $file rast2
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately it's now saying unable to find layer /mnt/hgfs/Shared/SHAPE1, skipping.

Comment: You need to figure out what the layer is named.  If the layer is named SHAPE1, try `$(basename ${file%.shp})`

Comment: I forgot `file` was the full path name! Updating, using `basename` to strip off the suffix as well.